# Issues with a JavaScript drop down menu function

Tags: javascript, html, css

The only problem I have is when you go from one drop down menu title to the next menu drop down title the first one stays open, I have attached the code pen, hopefully that's allowed.

https://codepen.io/gsxr1000/pen/yrGWEd

Edit: The below solutions are great, but they all lose the toggle ablilty of the menu, meaning the menu cant drop down and back up by clicking on the same menu item. This is very important to the functionality of the menu as in some small phones the drop downs could take up most of the screen so they will have no way to close the open dropdowns.

```js
function blockchain() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropone");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}

function products() {
  var element = document.getElementById("droptwo");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}

function payments() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropthree");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}

function services() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropfore");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.subnavbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mystyle')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-left: px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.subnav:last-child {
  border-right: ;
}

.subnav:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 1px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50;
  border-top: none;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.subnav-content a:nth-child(4n-3) {
  border-left: none;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #2c602e;
}

.mystyle {
  display: block;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .subnav-content a {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .subnav-content a:nth-child(2n-1) {
    border-left: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="blockchain()">Blockchain</button>
    <div class="subnav-content" class="drop1" id="dropone">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="products()">Products</button>
    <div class="subnav-content" class="drop2" id="droptwo">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="payments()">Payments</button>
    <div class="subnav-content" class="drop3" id="dropthree">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="services()">Services</button>
    <div class="subnav-content" class="drop4" id="dropfore">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! What is your problem?

Comment: On the code pen, you can basically open all menu dropdowns by clicking on each, not sure how to fix. need to so a js loop or something.

Comment: Would you mind a css only solution that does not require JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a function to close all navigation items;
2. Call this function when navigation items are clicked or document are clicked.

```js
function blockchain() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropone");
  if (element.classList.contains("mystyle")) {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  } else {
    closeAll();
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
  }
}
function products() {
  var element = document.getElementById("droptwo");
  if (element.classList.contains("mystyle")) {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  } else {
    closeAll();
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
  }
}
function payments() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropthree");
  if (element.classList.contains("mystyle")) {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  } else {
    closeAll();
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
  }
}
function services() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropfore");
  if (element.classList.contains("mystyle")) {
    element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  } else {
    closeAll();
    element.classList.add("mystyle");
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  closeAll(event);
}

function closeAll(event = null) {
  if (!event || !event.target.matches('.subnavbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("subnav-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mystyle')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}


.navbar{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-left: px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.subnav:last-child {
  border-right: ;
}

.subnav:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 1px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50;
  border-top: none;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  color:white;
}

.subnav-content a:nth-child(4n-3) {
  border-left: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #2c602e;
}

.mystyle {
  display:block;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .subnav-content a {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .subnav-content a:nth-child(2n-1) {
  border-left: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="blockchain()">Blockchain</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop1" id="dropone">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="products()">Products</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop2" id="droptwo">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="payments()">Payments</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop3" id="dropthree">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn" onclick="services()">Services</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop4" id="dropfore">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

More simply practice with jQuery:

```js
$('.subnav').on('click', function() {
  $('.subnav').not(this).find('.subnav-content').removeClass('mystyle');
  $(this).find('.subnav-content').toggleClass('mystyle');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('subnavbtn')) {
    $('.subnav-content').removeClass('mystyle');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}


.navbar{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-left: px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.subnav:last-child {
  border-right: ;
}

.subnav:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 1px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50;
  border-top: none;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  color:white;
}

.subnav-content a:nth-child(4n-3) {
  border-left: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #2c602e;
}

.mystyle {
  display:block;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .subnav-content a {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .subnav-content a:nth-child(2n-1) {
  border-left: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Blockchain</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop1" id="dropone">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Products</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop2" id="droptwo">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Payments</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop3" id="dropthree">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Services</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop4" id="dropfore">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If the answer helps you, please accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: I only have one problem, you can't toggle the drop down menu, say you click on one, then click on the same one again it still stays active, not toggled.... like you cant make it drop down then drop up again by clicking on it again.

Comment: Updated the snippet by adding some logic in javascript. Not the best practice but just solve the problem according to your original coding.

Comment: What would be the best practice, this does solve all my problems but i would rather do it clean if possible :). Would it involve changing the html to suit a more user friendly function?

Comment: Added a snippet to show how to work simply with jQuery. FYR.

Answer (score 0):

A css only solution would make the problem much easier.

The `:focus` selector selects an element if it is the last one that was clicked.

The `:focus-within` does the same but also if any child has focus.

The `+` selects the next sibling, which in your case is a div with the .subnav-content

```css
/*
 * When the button is focused this makes it click-through.
 * This hast the efect that when the user clicks the button again the click event
 * goes through the button and 'hits' the element behind it and so the button looses focus.
 */
.subnavbtn:focus, .subnavbtn:focus-within {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.subnavbtn:focus + .subnav-content, .subnavbtn:focus-within + .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}



body {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}


.navbar{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-left: px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.subnav:last-child {
  border-right: ;
}

.subnav:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #4caf50;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 1px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50;
  border-top: none;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  color:white;
}

.subnav-content a:nth-child(4n-3) {
  border-left: none;
}

.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #2c602e;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .subnav-content a {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subnav .subnavbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .subnav-content a:nth-child(2n-1) {
  border-left: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Blockchain</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop1" id="dropone">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Products</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop2" id="droptwo">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Payments</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop3" id="dropthree">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Services</button>
      <div class="subnav-content" class="drop4" id="dropfore">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, seems CSS has grown a lot over the last few years :).. I am still stuck with the problem that clicking on the drop down again wont close it, it will just stay focused within. Only way with CSS will be some kind of radio button hack?

Comment: Sadly, yes as far as I know

Comment: I' ve updated my code and now the subnavs toggle when you click the button multiple times. It does not require any additional html. This is a hack obviously but it should work quite well